# How to generate a random mobile number starts with zero and have 10 digits, that starts with zero?

Tags: java, random, phone-number

My Friend ask me this question and i am posting it here, if you have better approach please share

```
 String getRandomMobileNumber() {
        double random = Math.random();
        Double randomten = random*1000000000.0;
        return "0"+Math.round(randomten);
    }
```

Comment: You should prefer the `Random` class over `Math.random()`.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that will _very_ rarely generate a valid phone number...

Comment: You're more likely to get a response if you provide information on the phone numbering scheme for your country, and maybe also a bit of context behind the requirement to put our minds at ease that you won't be using your code to make spam calls to random people.

Comment: You can [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your own questions, but you should [ask them first](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and say what you like (or do not like) about your current approach. As it stands, you have just posted some code. There's lots of code out there: what problem is yours solving? Why is it good, or better than other approaches? Without a question, it is hard to know.

Comment: One of my friend ask me this question, he wants random mobile numbers start with and have 9 numbers and then i thought if anyone else have this question they can use this question.

Comment: My intention was only to help, but giving this question negative points is not correct

Comment: I have edited the question, which makes more sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this, see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextInt-int-int-):

`String phoneNumber = "0" + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(10000000, 99999999);`